# Convert to a parallel_for

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a very basic understanding of parallel concurrent programming. 
I read through some articles and could convert simple for loop to parallel_for. 
However , I am confused with this conversion.

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::directory_iterator end_iter;
fs::path sourceDir( sourceDirectory );
for( fs::directory_iterator dir_iter( sourceDir ) ; dir_iter != end_iter ; ++dir_iter ) // Wish to convert this line.
```

Comment: you can convert a loop to parallel_for which carries no dependencies between iterations. I.e. only random-access iterators are convertible.

Comment: But you can consider other patterns in [tag:tbb] such as `parallel_do` and `parallel_pipeline`

Comment: @Anton an example would be worthy..I went through tbb example that's for nested loop. that is as simple for loop